# cannot git clone or push into vps server

Tags: git, ssh, vps, digital-ocean

The problem is every time i do git push (clone) to fakhrul@ipdaresss:/home/fakhrul/proj.git (or any git repo) i will get error (DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 server)

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I already did lot of research and try every tutorial, but the problem still there. So, i think maybe i did miss something basic.

For this, i hope you can answer as talking to really beginner.

**What i use?**
i use Git Bash in Windows, so basically everything is simillar to linux

**What i already done**
i have a user (fakhrul) with sudo access with functional ssh key
i can ssh fakhrul@ipadress
i done initial setup (firewall), install LEMP, git
i successfully create plain laravel project from this tutorial

the only problem is git

**Is git is properly install and setup in my local pc and server?**
git init works in both server and local

**What i understand when to use git and what i did?**
*but fail to clone or push (from or to vps server)*

1 create repo in local

```
mkdir proj; cd proj ;
# create index.html using notepad with "hello world" in it
git init
git add *
git commit -m "first commit"
```

2 create repo in server with git bare

```
ssh fakhrul@ipaddress
mkdir proj.git; cd proj.git
git init --bare
exit
```

3 back in local to push to server

```
# in proj dir
git remote add origin fakhrul@ipadress:/home/fakhrul/proj.git
git push origin master
```

then i get this

```
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

- already open git port sudo ufw allow git. but i didnt think this is because i using ssh with git.
- already ask the question in DigitalOcean community forums
- [updated] git clone repo from github works

Comment: This error should be raised when you did not connect to Internet. Did you check that ?

Comment: i on slow internet connection but i did use browser at the same time. so internet connection should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GREAT** [solved]

**What i did to solved this?**

1. uninstall Git For Windows
2. download Git For Windows 1.9.5 and install by choosing all default choices (use openssh)
3. now git push over ssh working

**What is the problem?**

I am not sure, but the problem may be because of Git and putty. I installed Git for long time ago and with less knowledge at that time. 
Using putty we need to run Pageant with private keys set, i dont understand this. Putty use .ppk format for private key, but i always use `ssh-keygen` in Git Bash for creating ssh keys.

Thank you for everyone who views this and try to help.

:: i have new problem `write failed :connection reset by peer`, but this will go for another thread (if i cannot solved by own research)